# Bounded and differentiable functions on $R$ with with bounded derivatives on $R$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am a looking at functions that are in $BC(\mathbb{R})$, the space of bounded and continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I now need to express some extra regularity, namely I want functions in $BC(\mathbb{R})$ that are also differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, and whose derivatives are in $BC(\mathbb{R})$.

Is there a standard name/notation for such space?

Thank you.

Comment: For functions that **are** bounded derivatives, I've seen [$D$ and $\mathcal D$ and $b\mathcal D$ and $b\Delta'$ used](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bounded+derivative%22+Bruckner+space), so while $D$ or $bD$ might be a natural choice, you probably want to use something else. Whatever you use, you might want to distinguish between having a finite derivative on a given set, having a bounded derivative on a given set, and having a continuous derivative on a given set.

Answer (score 1):

An everywhere differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if it has a bounded first derivative. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties). In particular, I think you want to talk about the set of bounded and everywhere differentiable Lipschitz continuous functions whose derivatives (of all orders) are Lipschitz continuous and everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, I need to have: boundedness and continuity of f, existence of f', and boundedness of f'. So, from what I understand, I should consider the set of bounded and everywhere differentiable Lipschitz continuous functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, because being Lipschitz guarantees existence and boundedness of f'. Do  you agree?

Comment: Being differentiable guarantees the existence of $f'$ while being Lipschitz guarantees the boundedness of $f'$. You also need to stipulate that $f'$ is continuous. That way, as you put it, you are talking about the subset of $BC(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of differentiable functions whose derivatives are bounded and continuous.

Comment: I should say being Lipschitz in addition to its being everywhere differentiable